# Calculation of the source term for the Einstein-Dirac equation in the weak field limit

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have seen the same being done for Einstein- Klein Gordon equations quite successfully. However, I'm struggling with it in the case of the E-D equations. I know that the einstein equations in the limit of weak field reduce to the poisson's equation given by:
$$ \nabla^{2}V = 8 \pi G S_{00} $$
Here, the $S_{\mu\nu}$ is the source term which is given by $T_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}T$

I have calculated the stress energy tensor using the lagrangian given by $L = \frac{1}{2}\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu\psi - m\overline{\psi}\psi. $ and I've used the following formula to calculate the energy momentum tensor for the given lagrangian $$T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\overline{\psi})}\partial_\mu\psi + \frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\nu\psi)}\partial_\mu\overline{\psi} - \eta_{\mu\nu} L.
$$ it comes out to:
$$T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\nu\psi \partial_\mu\psi - \gamma^\nu\overline{\psi} \partial_\mu\overline{\psi}) - \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^\nu\overline{\psi} \partial_\mu\psi - \gamma^\nu\psi \partial_\mu\overline{\psi}) - \eta_{\mu\nu} \left(\frac{1}{2}\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi - \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu\psi - m\overline{\psi}\psi\right)$$
I'm using the minkowski metric in spherical polar coordinates given by $\text{diag}(1, -1, -r^2, -r^2\sin^2\theta)$ using this expression for $T_{\mu\nu}$ we  can calculate its trace and using the above equation for the source term, we get $S_{00}$ as:
$$S_{00}=\frac{1}{2}\overline{\psi} \gamma^0 \partial_0 \psi - \frac{1}{2}\partial_0 \overline{\psi} \gamma^0 \psi + m\overline{\psi} \psi$$
For static solution, using $\psi= e^{-i\omega t} \psi(r,\theta)$ we get :
$$S_{00}=-m \overline{\psi} \gamma^0 \psi + m\overline{\psi} \psi$$

I'm not sure whether my calculations so far are actually correct. Can someone please tell me if my calculation of the source term in this case is correct. I also am not sure if the energy momentum tensor is spherically symmetric.